# How to adjust the figure to the cell height?

Tags: tables, floats, size, cell

I have a table as follows 
'''

```
 \begin{table*}
 \centering
 \caption{******}
 \label{my-label}
 \begin{tabular}{ m{3cm} m{4cm} m{5cm}  }
 \toprule
 \textbf{Behavior}  
     &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} & \textbf{Formula} \\ 
 \midrule           
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,trim = 10 10 10 10,clip=true] 
  {separation.jpg}  
  & Separation: 
  &
  $\begin{aligned} 
  f_{s_{i}}=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
  g(d_{ij}) =
  \begin{cases} 
        1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
       exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
  \end{aligned}$    
 \\ \hline
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,trim = 10 10 10 10,clip=true] 
 {alignment.jpg}  
 & Alignment:  
 &
 $\begin{aligned} 
 f_{s_{i}}=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
 g(d_{ij}) =
   \begin{cases} 
        1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
       exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
     \end{cases}
   \end{aligned}$
   \\ \hline 
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,trim = 10 10 10 10,clip=true] 
   {cohesion.jpg}  
  & Cohesion:
   &
   $\begin{aligned}
   f_{s_{i}}=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
   g(d_{ij}) =
    \begin{cases} 
        1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
        exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
   \end{cases}    
   \end{aligned}$

  \end{tabular}
  \end{table*}
```

How is it possible to have the second two pictures look like the first one (same size)?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. And, does your document use a two-column layout? The reason I ask is that your code uses a `table*` environment; this seems to suggest that the document has two columns per page. Is this conjecture correct? A separate issue: Your code contains a `figure` environment, yet the screenshot does not. Is this intentional?

Comment: I am using a two-column layout, but I use table* to create a page-wide table in a two-column mode. I am trying to insert 3 figures in table in a way that each figure is put in a cell.

Answer (score 2):

What I understood from "the same size" is you mean same width? In this case, you can store the width of the first picture in a new length like `\newlength\picone` and use that measure in the following pictures. The `\fbox`es are only used to show the width, also remove that `\centering` before second picture. (All the pictures here are courtesy of Google)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,array,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\newlength\picone
\settowidth\picone{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,trim = 10 10 10 10,clip=true]{separation.jpg}}

\begin{figure}[!t]
 \centering
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=2.2in,trim = 10 10 10 10,clip=true]{flocks.jpg}}

 \caption{********** }
\label{fig_1}
\end{figure}


 \begin{table*}
 \centering
 \caption{******}
 \label{my-label}
 \begin{tabular}{ m{3cm} m{4cm} m{5cm}  }
 \toprule
 \textbf{Behavior}  
     &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} & \textbf{Formula} \\ 
 \midrule           
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,trim = 10 10 10 10,clip=true] 
  {separation.jpg}}  
  & Separation: 
  &
  $\begin{aligned} 
  f_{s_{i}}=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
  g(d_{ij}) =
  \begin{cases} 
        1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
       exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
  \end{cases}
  \end{aligned}$    
 \\ \hline
 %\centering
 \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\picone,trim = 10 10 10 10,clip=true] 
 {alignment.jpg}}  
 & Alignment:  
 &
 $\begin{aligned} 
 f_{s_{i}}=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
 g(d_{ij}) =
   \begin{cases} 
        1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
       exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
     \end{cases}
   \end{aligned}$
   \\ \hline 
   \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth,trim = 10 10 10 10,clip=true] 
   {cohesion.jpg}}  
  & Cohesion:
   &
   $\begin{aligned}
   f_{s_{i}}=-\frac{w_{s}}{n_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}g(d_{ij})d_{ij} \\
   g(d_{ij}) =
    \begin{cases} 
        1 & d_{ij}\leq r_{h}\\
        exp(-\frac{(d_{ij}-r_{h})^{2}}{\sigma^{2}})   & d_{ij}> r_{h}
   \end{cases}    
   \end{aligned}$

  \end{tabular}
  \end{table*} 


\end{document}
```

> [image]